# Types of property 'length' are incompatible. Type '4' is not assignable to type '1'

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm learning typescript / angular at the moment and can't work out why TSLint is throwing this up as an error, however the code itself works and displays in a browser.

```
export class GreetingComponent implements OnInit {

  names: [{ name: string }] = [{ name: 'Tom' }, { name: 'Dave' }, { name: 'Katie' }, { name: 'John' }];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

Specifically the line:

```
 names: [{ name: string }] = [{ name: 'Tom' }, { name: 'Dave' }, { name: 'Katie' }, { name: 'John' }];
```

Full Error:

```
[ts]
Type '[{ name: string; }, { name: string; }, { name: string; }, { name: string; }]' is not assignable to type '[{ name: string; }]'.
  Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
    Type '4' is not assignable to type '1'.
(property) GreetingComponent.names: [{
        name: string;
    }]
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The type:

```
[{name: string}]
```

is a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) of one element. So that type can only be an array with a single item in it. If you're wanting the type to be an array of any length filled with those objects, it would be written as

```
{name: string}[]

// Or if you prefer:

Array<{name: string}>
```

Comment: Ah perfect. Has that changed? It's not in my tutorial i'm following, same goes for adding a const ''' export const PEOPLE [] = [{ name: 'Tom' }, { name: 'Dave' }, { name: 'Katie' }, { name: 'John' }];'''

Comment: In my case, in a similar issue, only the second version worked (Array<Object>). In the first version (Object[]), my array was still interpreted as a tuple. Not clear for me why though.

Comment: It is all Swift's fault.

Answer (score 3):

In case of this:

```
names: [{ name: string }] = [{ name: 'Tom' }, { name: 'Dave' }, { name: 'Katie' }, { name: 'John' }];
```

You should write this:

```
names: { name: string }[] = [{ name: 'Tom' }, { name: 'Dave' }, { name: 'Katie' }, { name: 'John' }];
```

And for the second version of code it will work well.